# how to build in store map dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to build a in-store navigation app for a grocery store in Flutter.

My initial approach is to create a 2d map of the store using buttons.

i want to ask is there a better way to do it or is it even possible.

[Grocery store map][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKgSs.png

This is an image of a grocery store what i am thinking to make this interactable is to place the button widget o top of every rack manually and when the customers complete his grocery list those particular racks will be highlighted.

is there way where i donot have to buld this map manually?

or is it even possible.

Comment: is there really no other ??